# error installing new version of php in EasyApache 4

Tags: linux, php, cloudlinux

I have a small cloudserver running `cloudlinux`, which has `WHM` installed to manage it, in addition to `EasyApache 4` so I need to install a new version of php for my server in this case `php73`, when installing I get this error in the panel:

**Update Error:**

```
Error: Package: 1:ea-libcurl-7.69.1-2.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl-ea4)
Requires: libssh2 >= 1.8.0
Installed: libssh2-1.4.3-10.el7_2.1.x86_64 (@updates)
libssh2 = 1.4.3-10.el7_2.1
Error: Package: 2:ea-apache24-mod_security2-2.9.3-4.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl-ea4)
Requires: yajl
Error: Package: 2:ea-apache24-mod_security2-2.9.3-4.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cl-ea4)
Requires: libyajl.so.2()(64bit)
The entire output was logged to: /usr/local/cpanel/logs/packman/errors/2020-04-19_14:52:52-1
```

So why is this error, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have CentOS repos enabled that should be disabled.
This command should help you in this matter:

```
# mv /etc/cl-convert-saved/CentOS-* /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

Thanks

Comment: thank you, let me install a new version of php